# Exporting Test Cases with Attachments?

Tags: manual-testing, testcase, export

So we send out clients our test cases to help them with their UAT process and ensure they are testing our integrations properly.

Is there a TCMS on the market that actually exports test cases with the attached screenshots? Everything I see is a CSV file.

Comment: The few ones I've used or evaluated had an option to print test cases along with attachments.

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice idea to help guide the UAT testing in the right direction, bu also educate clients on how tests are set out.

Instead of exporting the test cases to send to your client, is it more suitable to allow them to have access to your TCMS system?

This will most likely save you the effort and time of having to export them manually, but ensure that they also have access to the latest set of test cases, allow them to contribute to the tests themselves (if you provide write access), and may even increase your reputation with them if they see the efforts that you go to.

Answer (score 0):

As a software qa consulting company, we recommend that in order to help clients with UAT test, it is always better to provide client access with the TCMS tool where the test cases reside.
However, in case you need to export test cases with attachments, than you can use HP ALM (paid test case management tool) for the same.